# Can you automate putting a field on a page layout across ALL profiles?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm working in Salesforce, and  need to add a currency field to my Contacts object and put in the same section across all profiles.

Is there a way to do this without manually adjusting the page layout for each and every profile? There are a number of page layouts for each profile and Record type and would love a  better approach

Thanks,

-The new guy.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the field you are given the option to add the field to each page layout and each profile.  You will have to go through each *page layout* to move the field into the appropriate section, but after initial creation there should be no need to go back through each profile.

You may want to explore using the Force.com IDE to manage your page layouts.  A section of page layout may look something like this:

```
<layoutSections>
    <customLabel>true</customLabel>
    <detailHeading>false</detailHeading>
    <editHeading>true</editHeading>
    <label>Contact Information</label>
    <layoutColumns>
        <layoutItems>
            <behavior>Required</behavior>
            <field>Name</field>
        </layoutItems>
        <layoutItems>
            <behavior>Edit</behavior>
            <field>AccountId</field>
        </layoutItems>
     </layoutColumns>
</layoutSections>
```

Once you figure out how to change one layout, it should be a simple matter to copy-paste your update across a number of layouts.